# Invaild Bounce rate in google analytics

Tags: google-analytics, google-ads-api

I am now working in a SaaS company which focus in B2B market. 
Now I am facing a question, which I have no idea why it happens.

The question is: The bounce rate is too low according to google analytics. 
Of course, this is normally a good sign, but below 3% bounce rate would not be true, especially significant traffic are searching for dating sesrvice, which is totally irrelevant to our business and I suspect there are some BOTs that brush the statistic.

Does anyone face the same question before, and how can I tackle it?
Many thanks for your help in advance!

Comment: Most likely reason is that you have an event tracking call that is executed (almost) every time and does not have the non-interaction flag set. So you have two interactions on every page, thus no bounces.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because its about Google analytics the application and is not programing related.

Answer (score 0):

The most common reason for such a low bounce rate is a duplicated tracking code on the site. This happens because the tracking

You can test your tracking code installation using the [Tag Manager Assistant extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tag-assistant-by-google/kejbdjndbnbjgmefkgdddjlbokphdefk) on Chrome.

The use of the extension is pretty straight forward just install, enable and open the site you want to test.

If you are having issues with the implementation you will see something like this.
[image: enter image description here----------------------------]